# add a customized object to tinyDB

Tags: android, object, casting, type-conversion

`tinydb.putListObject(String,java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Object>)` wants an object but I want to store restaurant object. How can I solve it?

```
ArrayList<Restaurant> restaurants = new ArrayList<>();

// This part gives error.
tinydb.putListObject("restaurantsObject",restaurants);
```

After that, I need to convert it to restaurant object in different class.

```
ArrayList<Restaurant> restaurants = new ArrayList<>();

restaurants = tinydb.getListObject("restaurantsObject", Restaurant.class);
```

Also, If you know easy caching method for my structure, you can share with me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used gson to store it.

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 ArrayList<String> gsonString = new ArrayList<>();
 for(int i=0; i<restaurants.size(); i++)
      gsonString.add(gson.toJson(restaurants.get(i)));
 tinydb.putListString("tinyRestaurant",gsonString);
```

Convert it

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 for(int i=0; i<tinydb.getListString("tinyRestaurant").size(); i++)
            restaurants.add(gson.fromJson(tinydb.getListString("tinyRestaurant").get(i), Restaurant.class));
```